# How to search for file names in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, search, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-mac

In **Eclipse** you can search for a file in the project by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>.

Is there a way to do this in **Visual Studio**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to quickly find files in Visual Studio 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667528/is-there-a-way-to-quickly-find-files-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: ps, i know this question was asked earlier, but the better, more correct answer is in the linked file.

Comment: No offense, but this feels horrible after CTRL+p of sublime text.

Answer (score 677, accepted):

Just for anyone else landing on this page from Google or elsewhere, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2685216/573634) is probably the best answer out of all of them.

To summarize, simply hit:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

And then start typing the file name.

Comment: How is this not the number 1 answer?

Comment: @dkroy: ... because it didn't exist when the question was asked. In 2009, it was really a problem to search for files or classes in VS without additional tools.

Comment: Well it's not 2009 anymore but people are still coming to this question to get answers, so the updated answer makes sense. :)

Comment: I probably waste 30 minutes every day just looking for the correct file in the Solution Explorer. This is my new favorite shortcut!

Comment: This shows method names as well though, bit annoying.

Comment: This is so weird that it automatically opens the file while I'm typing the name, causing me accidentally change the file.

Comment: @Deqing I have not had that happen.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't limit the search to filenames, it also includes symbols

Comment: Not sure if this accurately answers the question, this thing searches for symbols as wells (methods etc) which is very annoying in a large project. Furthermore, the same thing could be achieved by `Ctrl+;` which is shortcut for search in solution explorer.

Comment: For thoses of you that are using Resharper the Ctrl + , only opens the recent files window. If you happen to use Resharper Ctrl + t will search the entire solution. @Johannes might want to add that

Comment: @marsh In VS 2017.3 (and possibly earlier) Ctrl-, behaves like a command window somewhat. If you give it the 'f' command and provide a file name, it will search only files: e.g. "f someFile.cpp". There's also a button that prepends the "f" if you prefer clicking.

Comment: 250 people must have small enough projects that searching through symbols mixed up with files isn't a problem. This answer is not ideal.

Comment: Ctrl+1, Ctrl+F opens the dialog for searching from OPs answer directly with file search. It is equivalent to Press Ctrl+, (or Ctrl+T, Edit.GoToAll) and then typing t.

Comment: Make sure you have the solution open, lol, or it doesn't work! Took me a few minutes to figure out why it wasn't working 

Comment: What if this doesn't work? That shortcut does bring up the small panel to type in but it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: This gives me the options window in VS2019.

Comment: The best part about the feature is the smart search. If you want to find filename, SomeReallyLongFileName, you can just type the capitalized letter. "srlfn" Try it!!!

Comment: this doesnt work for visual studio code - Ctrl+, opens setting. I just saw you can Ctrl+Shft+F

Comment: CTRL + comma is good to search IN files contents and names. CTRL + T wins for searching in filenames.

Comment: if(from Google || from elsewhere) is always true 

Answer (score 74):

In VS2013 you can click in the solution explorer for this functionality.

The shortcut is:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>

[image]

To search only the names of files, and not the contents (especially in C#), uncheck these options:

[image]

Comment: Great and useful. I am using VS 2019 preview and it works perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 61):

The best option now is to install Microsoft Visual Studio add on called Productivity Power Tools ([VS 2010 version](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef), [VS 2013 version](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace)).

With this comes "Solution Navigator" (alternative to Solution Explorer, with a lot of benefits).

[image: search solution navigator]

BTW, this feature is built-in into Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Built in to 2017!

Answer (score 51):

With **`Visual Studio 2017`**, It now comes with a much better version, named **`“Go To All”`** and is bound to the keyboard shortcut `CTRL + T` as well as **`CTRL +,`** and includes inline filtering and **[`“fuzzy search”`](http://www.depthinfinity.com/2017/04/alternative-resharper-functionality-within-visual-studio-2017/)**

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

Comment: YES, finally they added a built-in way to filter _only_ by filenames! Type `f`, space, then the filename. Example: `CTRL+T` then `f MyClass`, then ↓ on your keyboard until you get to the matching file. This method is superior to the solution explorer search (which wastes space by showing both filenames and class names) in that it is strictly filenames only.

Comment: You can even add a custom keyboard shortcut in Tools -> Options -> Keyboard -> Edit.GoToFile which adds the `f` for you.

Comment: The default for `Edit.GoToFile` is Ctrl+1, Ctrl+F. There are more with Ctrl+1, Ctrl+<key>. F=Files, M=Members, R=Recent Files, T=Types

Comment: Link in answer is dead - domain is for sale.

Comment: Thanks for naming the action, something everybody else forgets about. Some people want to learn how to remap it.

Answer (score 28):

Easily hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> . This will look in the files' names.

Comment: This is super useful! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 15):

In the search dropdown on the standard toolbar, you can use the "open file" macro, >of, to find files. Click in said dropdown (or hit Ctrl-D) then start typing (minus the quotes) ">of CoreEdit.cs", and you'll get a dynamic list that narrows as you type.

Answer (score 9):

In Visual Studio 2017 you can search [directly for files](https://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2017/06/14/new-code-navigation-shortcuts-in-visual-studio-2017/) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (Keyboard command: Edit.GoToFile).

Alternatively, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> (the Edit.GoToAll command) and start your search with <kbd>f</kbd>.

Answer (score 7):

I believe what you are searching for is this **Ctrl+T**. With this you can search for symbols inside files and also can search files if you **remove the hash(#) symbol**.

See the screenshot if having doubts.
[image: Search Shortcut on Windows for VS Code]

Comment: This answer is regarding Visual Code, not Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6):

Since you mention ReSharper in a comment:

You can do this in ReSharper by using the "Goto File..." option (Ctrl-Shift-N or ReSharper -> Go To -> File...) in my key mappings.

Comment: @Andomar: Yes, it depends on whether you have the Visual Studio or IDEA shortcuts configured.

Answer (score 4):

I use usysware DPack: http://www.usysware.com/dpack/

Then I just press ALT-U start typing the filename and choose the correct file. DPack also has other nice features.

[image]

(highlights added for screenshot)

**Note:** Will not work in Express editons of Visual Studio, since they don't allow plugins.

Comment: interesting, does it conflict with resharper do you know?

Comment: Works for me, but resharper got file search ctrl-shift-t

Comment: i already use DPack (Delphi Pack) for their brief bookmarks. i didn't realize they also had unit search. Sad that Delphi's 10 year old IDE is more developer friendly than Visual Studio. People don't *realize* what they're missing; how sloppy VS is.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Assist: [link](http://www.wholetomato.com/).

Install, load solution, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, search for files in solution by substring. Try also <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, for the equivalent for symbols. This addin has a bunch of completion popup and syntax colouring stuff in it that aren't to all tastes, but the code browsing features are done well and seem uncontroversial.

Judging by comments on the forums, compatibility with Resharper is something they pay attention to.

For free, try also Nifty Solution: [link](http://code.google.com/p/niftyplugins/).

I haven't used this myself, but I use the author's Nifty Perforce plugin, and that is pretty tidy.

Comment: nifty solution is excellent. Its simple and it works. It also adds "toggle between header/source" which I like.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend [PhatStudio](http://phatstudio.sourceforge.net/) if you're using upto VS 2012. Works pretty fast, and supports multi-word search by using "space". So to search for LoginController, you could press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and search using "Lo Con".

[image]

You could also use ReSharper (paid) and CodeMaid (free) to do this.

Answer (score 3):

## Visual Studio for Mac 2017 7.x.x

To search by File name:

- <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

To search by Type name:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Your keyboard focus might have been gone to following **Right side Top corner of the Visual Studio Window**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Open command window( View -> Other windows -> command window - Ctrl + W, A) type >of followed by the file name. It would start showing up the list as you type.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily call for a window called "Navigate To" with combination **ctrl + ,**

Or, go to **Tools** and then click **Navigate To**

Comment: On visual studio 2012 it is ->EDIT ->Navigate To or ctrl+,

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> this searches for the file name your direct answer.

Comment: Not true for Visual Studio, only vs code. This actually opens the print dialog.

Answer (score 2):

You can press ctrl+t to get a editor Get to all , in which you can type the file name to navigate to that specific file.

Answer (score 1):

With Visual Studio 2017 Community edition **on mac**, the shortcut is:

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>: Find by file name
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>: Find by type name

To see these commands, navigate to the top menu: Search > Go To

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2022 -- Couple of ways

1. As per screenshot 1 <Ctrl + Shift + T> , But that doesnt work with that key combination, although it works with mouse click.
   [image: Screenshot 1]
2. As per screenshot 2 go to menu **Edit** -> **Go To** - > **Go To File** <**Alt + E + G + F**>

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

Is too simple by using the Windows Explorer search inside the project folder. Done.

Comment: Add an index and that's a killer solution!

Comment: This option wouldn't work for ftp sites loaded in visual studio. In vs2013 Ctrl + semi colon allows you to search the solution explorer quickly by filename without leaving the window.

Comment: I am using VS 2010 and I wanted to open all the code behind files of my User Controls (i.e `.ascx.cs` files). Really your solution is straight forward and useful

Comment: b/c I love bouncing between Windows Explorer and Vs.NEt , yeah right.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2008 (and probably later), the free DevExpress CodeRush Xpress add-in supplies <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, [Quick File Navigation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/CodeRush/CustomDocument6535.aspx), which searches on an exact substring in the file name or on capital letters.

(Unrelated to this answer, but note the rather more useful, [Quick Navigation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/CodeRush/CustomDocument3547.aspx), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, which I would have liked to have known about before now :-) )

Answer (score 0):

**Visual Studio 2019:**

Menu -> Preferences -> Key Bindings -> Navigate To...