# Visual Studio 2008 - Quick Find File Shortcuts - like textmate on macs

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I recently moved from a Mac + Textmate back to Visual Studio.

The one thing I absolutely loved about textmate was it's find/search feature.  It made navigating solution files so easy.  Is there an equivalent shortcut/addon for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't explained what Textmate does for you, but...

- The "folder + binoculars" icon in the toolbar gives "search in files"
- Ctrl-F brings up Find
- Ctrl-Click on a method call goes to its declaration (etc for other member types too)

If you want "find a type" or "find a file" easily in VS2008 (e.g. type SE to find SmartEnumerable), you'll need [ReSharper](http://jetbrains.com/resharper)

Comment: textmate is simple: ctrl-t=autocomplete file search, ctrl-shit-t=autocomplete text search

I just dont like how vs.net ouputs the results in a different window.  SonicfileFinder is all inline which seems to do the trick..

Comment: Have a look at the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508973/how-to-search-for-file-names-in-visual-studio/1509131