# How to create constructor of ThisAddIn class in VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop

Using `VS2019`, I have created a [VSTO AddIn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/create-vsto-add-ins-for-office-by-using-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) WORD project. As we know the default template of this project creates a [ThisAddIn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/programming-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019#use-the-thisaddin-class) class with two events `ThisAddIn_Startup` and `ThisAddIn_Shutdown` but no constructor. But when I try to create a constructor of this class as follows, I get the following error:

```
public ThisAddIn()
{
}
```

**Error**:

> there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'factory' of 'AddInBase.AddinBase(Factory, IserviceProvider, string, string)'

**Question**: What is the cause of this error and how can I create a constructor in `ThisAddIn` class?

**Some Background**: I am trying to mimic functionalities of a `Winform` (Windows Forms) project into a `VSTO` office project. The `Winform` project has some code inside its constructor `Form(){...}` that I need to implement inside the constructor of `ThisAddIn` class of VSTO projects.

Comment: Did you notice that ThisAddin is a partial class (look the file ThisAddin.Designer.cs) ? you can just create a constructor in the same way.ThisAddin is based on AddInBase that requires the 4 arguments. You may also try to override AddInBase.BeginInit .

Comment: @Malick Good point. How do I access `ThisAddin.Designer.cs`? In my `VS2019` VSTO project it's only showing `ThisAddin.cs` under `Word` folder.

Comment: We are not supposed to modify it because it is auto-generated. You can navigate to if via  `CTRL` + `,`  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508973/how-to-search-for-file-names-in-visual-studio ) and enter `ThisAddin.Designer.cs` . It is not available via the solution explorer.  It is just usefull to understand the class. I believe you could try to implement your code inside BeginInit.