# How to initialise ThisAddIn class?

Tags: c#, outlook, nunit, vsto, outlook-addin

I've to write unit tests for VSTO Plugin code. So, in my plugin, there is the main add-in class, `ThisAddIn` which has following declaration:

```cs
namespace NS
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {  private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e){...}
        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e){...}
    }
}
```

Now, I can see in IDE that this is how it's being initialised in `ThisAddIn.Designer.cs` class:

```cs
 [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public ThisAddIn(global::Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.Factory factory, global::System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider) : 
                base(factory, serviceProvider, "AddIn", "ThisAddIn") {
            Globals.Factory = factory;
        }
```

I referred this post: [How to create constructor of ThisAddIn class in VSTO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61134040/how-to-create-constructor-of-thisaddin-class-in-vsto) But could not take find something which will help me.
Reason of explicitly creating this class's object is for writing unit tests for VSTO plugin.
How can I create these input parameters and pass into the constructor call?
Also, is this the right way to write unit test for the VSTO plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless you recreate all the plumbing for hosting VSTO addins (See `IManagedAddin` interface on MSDN - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/imanagedaddin-interface?view=vs-2022), but that is a lot of work just for unit tests.

Comment: That's bit of a work. Instead, I'll create a new interface/class and put all the functionality in that and just use in the add-in class.

Comment: I would imagine you'd need to test various methods that use Application and other OOM objects. You won't be able to do that outside of the addin.

Comment: Yes, i guess. I think otherwise code which doesn't need Outlook interactions will cover more than 50% of codebase and that should suffice the code coverage condition. Also, can't restructure the codebase again just for unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock up everything you need in unit tests. `ThisAddin` is just an implementation of the `IDTExtensibility2` interface which all COM add-ins should implement. You may consider creating and implementing your own interface which can be tested and mocked up for the add-in class.

`ThisAddin` class can't be created by others. Instead, the VSTO runtime creates an instance of this class.